# Prove the convergence of a sequence with the Mean Value Theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, convergence-divergence

I am given the following problem: 
 
Let f: *R*$\rightarrow$*R* be differentiable such that,  for some $\alpha$ $\in$ *R*, $\left|f'(x)\right|$$\leq$ $\alpha$ $<1$ for all $x$$\in$ *R*. 
 Let  $a_{1}$$\in$ *R* and $a_{n+1}$ $=$ $f$($a_{n}$), for $n$ $\in$ *R*.
 Show that the sequence $a_{n+1}$ converges. 
 
Since it is an exercise of the chapter of the book about the Mean Value Theorem, I think I have to apply it, but I do not know where and what I can obtain in order to prove the convergence of the given sequence.

Comment: Use the mean value theorem to conclude that $|a_{n+1}-a_n|=|f(a_n)-f(a_{n-1})|=|f'(\xi)||a_n-a_{n-1}|$ for some $\xi\in\mathbb R, a_{n-1}\lt\xi\lt a_n$, i.e. $|a_{n+1}-a_n|\le\alpha|a_n-a_{n-1}|$ for every $n\in\mathbb N, n>1$. Then estimate $|a_n-a_m|$ (for $m,n\in\mathbb N$) using the triangle inequality. Finally, conclude that the original sequence $a_n$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Let $x,y\in\mathbb R$, then, there is $c_{x,y}\in [x,y]$ s.t. $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq |f'(c_{x,y})||x-y|\leq \alpha |x-y|.$$
Therefore, $f$ is a contraction. Your job now :

**1)** Prove that $$|a_{n+1}-a_n|\leq \alpha ^n|a_1-a_0|,$$
for all $n$.

**2)** Deduce that $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence.